# Why is it considered best practice?

Tags: javascript, scope, cycle

I saw this code on the site [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_best_practices.asp) (JavaScript Best Practices)

```js
// Declare at the beginning
var i;

// Use later
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

I don’t understand why declaring this variable is considered good practice. It is needed only for the cycle. Why should i make it global

Comment: Well it's not. You should be avoid global variable and w3schools as well ( pun intended ). Use MDN for better explained and updated reference

Comment: It would be global anyway (var doesn't create a block scope). This is (or was) actually a recommendation of var declarations, which are best to declare at the beginning of their scope (not ncecessarily global), because the declarations are hoisted anyway, and later declarations are ignored.

Comment: w3schools has improved, but for a long time it has displayed quite wrong informaiton. I wouldn't trust w3schools for best pratices. Use `let` instead of `var`in this case, at least.

Comment: Yes, but it can be replaced by `let`

Comment: if you are looking for any best practice on javascript use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials)

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Until this moment, I doubted, but now I understood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this code is outdated. The best practice is to use `let` instead of `var` ([see this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var), and declare it inside the for statement:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i); // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
}
console.log(i); // undefined variable i
```

The `let` defines a block scoped variable. This variable won't "bubble" up to the global scope, being more efficient by not polluting the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com):

> It is a good coding practice to put all declarations at the top of
>   each script or function.
>
> This will:
>
> Give cleaner code Provide a single place to look for local variables
>   Make it easier to avoid unwanted (implied) global variables 
>   Reduce the possibility of unwanted re-declarations

You can do it to make the code more cleaner.
But I recommend using `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: There we see w3schools striking again. Variables can't be re-declared in their scope.